# Message "1.13.1" A Problem in Load Fashion Mnist in Pycharm

Tags: python, keras

I am using "fashion Mnist using Keras" Toturial and I wrote Its codes in Python 3.6 , In first Time, These Codes Downloaded The Dataset Completely
But In Next Runs, I see Just "1.13.1" Message and "process finished with exit code 0" and Dataset didnt load into Pycharm.

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can see my repo https://github.com/rushu570/Fashion_Mnist 
the file is loaded when u print train and test data list it will print it.